# Problems in creating test script in ALM using OTA and JACOB

Tags: vbscript, jacob, hp-quality-center

I have created a piece of code in vbscript through which I am able to create test scripts in ALM via OTA.
Now I am trying to do the same thing through Java using JACOB as the Java 2 Com bridge and I have been able to create an empty test script using this, but I am not sure how to set the various field values.

VBScript Code (That works perfectly):

```
           Set tdc = CreateObject("TDAPIOLE80.TDConnection")
           If (tdc Is Nothing) Then
             MSGBOX "Connection is not created"
           Else
            MSGBOX "Connection is created"
           End If
           tdc.InitConnectionEx connectionString
           tdc.Login userName, password
           tdc.Connect domain, project
           Set TreeMgr = tdc.TreeManager
           Set testFolder = TreeMgr.NodeByPath(uploadDirectoryPath)
           Set testFactory = testFolder.TestFactory
           Set testItem = testFactory.AddItem (NULL)
           testItem.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")="Test script description"
           ...
```

Java code (Only that much that works)

```
     ActiveXComponent almConnection=new ActiveXComponent("TDAPIOLE80.TDConnection");
    Dispatch.call(almConnection, "InitConnectionEx", "conn string");        
    Dispatch.call(almConnection, "login", "uname","pword");
    Dispatch.call(almConnection, "connect","project","domain");     
    Dispatch treeMgr=Dispatch.get(almConnection, "TreeManager").toDispatch();
    Dispatch testFolder=Dispatch.call(treeMgr,"NodeByPath", "project path").toDispatch();
    Dispatch testFactory=Dispatch.get(testFolder, "TestFactory").toDispatch();              
    Dispatch testItem=Dispatch.call(testFactory,"AddItem","TO_BE_DELETED_SCRIPT9").toDispatch();
```

Now the issue is the last line in the VBScript code,

```
            testItem.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")="Test script description"
```

How do I code this in Java using JACOB?
Please help. I have done a lot of google searching, but haven't found anything substantial.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
Dispatch testItem=Dispatch.call(testFactory,"AddItem","TestName").toDispatch();
Dispatch.put(testItem, "Name", "newTestName");
Dispatch.call(testItem,"Post");
```

How to change field value in HPQC using JACOB:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/forums/forum/375946/topic/4830213